# Multi criteria, multi row search in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

I am working on a data set in excel that looks like this (image). I want to create a matrix as shown which maps the distance between each pair of nodal points. 
By using helper cells, I could map consecutive points like C and D. But I cannot map C with E and F. Is there a way to do it?

Column K,L,M is dataset, matrix is the required result. Same trip id means those people have been clubbed in same cab.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Get & Transform" > "From Table/Range" on the "Data" tabe of the ribbon to create a query from your data table. I've done that and called the query "data".

I then used "Home" > "Close & Load" in the PowerQuery editor to load the query into a new sheet.

I then clicked "Merge" on the Query tab on the ribbon and configured the dialog like this:

[image]

Performing an INNER JOIN between a table and itself on a column which has duplicate values (such as TRIP ID), will join each row with each other row with the same TRIP ID. So, you'd get this:

[image]

Clicking that double-arrow at the top-right corner of that grid would expand the "Table" into each row, and, if you filter on TRIP ID = 3, you would get this:

[image]

Now I can calculate the distance between each node and each other node in the same TRIP ID:

[image]

If I then load the query back to Excel and pivot the results, I get the matrix:

[image]